# Multiple statements in for

Tags: c#, c++

I have this code

```
for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++, Sleep(500*min(l, 8))) //... <= 4000 msec
  {
      ....
  }
```

would this be equivalent to this?

```
for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++) //... <= 4000 msec
  {
      Sleep(500*min(l, 8))
         ....
  }
```

I want to rewrite original code in C#. Is the second approach the same that is the way I will take in C#?

Comment: The final part of the `for( ; ;<this bit>)` is equivalent to happening at the *end* of the loop block. And in your original case, `l++` happens before the `Sleep`.

Comment: @BoBTFish Didn't get you can you elaborate?

Comment: You will loose one `l` count, making `int l = 0` in the modified version will help you

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.tenouk.com/clabworksheet/labworksheet7_files/cforloopflowchart008.png) can help (the source code for the image could be `for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i = i+1) print(1);`)

Comment: Did you try the original?  Most of the people answering here are going to be surprised that it works with only minor adjustments (min -> Math.Min).

Answer (score 4):

No they are not equivalent. The stopping condition of the `for` loop is executed after the code in the following `{ }` block.

So the equivalence is

```
for(int l = 1; l <= c; )
{
    /*loop body*/
    l++, Sleep(500 * min(l, 8));
}
```

The expression separator operator (`,`) *could* be replaced with the statement terminator `;`. As both are sequencing points, `Sleep` receives the incremented value of `l`.

Comment: Note that `l` is incremented before the `Sleep` in the original.

Comment: Oops. Silly old cat.

Comment: Ok but will it work the same if I write same code in C# ? Like this: `for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++, Sleep(500*min(l, 8)))` ??

Comment: @Bathsheba I am second guessing the call to `Sleep` in these code samples since `Sleep` returns `void`, is it really valid to use a void expression with the comma operator?

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent, as the third part of a `for` loop is executed in the end of each loop. Acording to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx), this is the syntax for a `for` loop.

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator) {
    body
}
```

Where

> The iterator section defines what happens **after** each iteration of the
>   body of the loop.

In your original case, `l++` is happening before `Sleep`, so this is the equivalent code:

```
for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++) //... <= 4000 msec
{
          ......
      Sleep(500*min(l+1, 8)) // note the +1
}
```

Comment: Technically the l++ happens before the call to Sleep in his loop, so the first sleep in his loop would be for 1 second and for yours it would be 500 ms.

Comment: @Neil That's why he added 1 to `l` when calling `Sleep`

Comment: Ok but will it work the same if I write same code in C# ? Like this: `for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++, Sleep(500*min(l, 8)))` ??

Comment: @user200312, yes it (the code with the sleep on the end and the `l+1` instead of `l` ) will

Comment: @GabrielIlharco: No I meant if in C# I will write same code as in my first version, e.g., in C#: `for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++, Thread.Sleep(500*min(l, 8)))`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, the code is equivalent to

```
for(int l = 1 ; l <= c;) //... <= 4000 msec
{
    // loop body goes here
    ...

    // statements from the last part of the for(...;...;...) statement are executed at the end of the loop
    l++;
    Sleep(500*min(l, 8));
}
```

Comment: Except that the `l++` should be executed before the call to `Sleep`.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde you are right, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your original code is equivalent to

```
{
    int l = 1 ;
    while( l <= c)
    {
        ....
        l++, Sleep(500*min(l, 8)); //... <= 4000 msec
    }
}
```

while the modified version is

```
{
    int l = 1 ;
    while( l <= c) //... <= 4000 msec
    {
        Sleep(500*min(l, 8));
        ....
        l++;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `l` is incremented after used to calculate `Sleep()` time, not before, as originally. Additionally, `Sleep()` is called before the main part of the loop body is executed, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int l = 0 ; l <= c ; l++, Sleep(500*min(l, 8))) //... <= 4000 msec
  {
  ....
  }
```

Note the change of `int l = 1` to int `l = 0` because you will be one count ahead so you have to tally it by reducing one count. So I made `l` to `0`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. In fact, it alters the original loop rather than making the new loop correct.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting alternative:

```
for(int l = 2 ; l <= c+1; l++) //... <= 4000 msec
{
  // ...
  Sleep(500*min(l, 8))
}
```

Similar to Gabriel's answer, but the `+ 1` is moved to the bounds check which keeps the rest looking the same. (the code feels suspect when adding the one to `l` in order to make up for the "missed" increment).

Since the question is also about porting the code to C#, here's the pertinent info. Although your two code samples aren't equivalent, they both translate directly to C# code (with C#'s equivalent to `Sleep`, of course). For C#, the more complex example found in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) makes it clear that when the iterator section of a `for` loop contains multiple expressions, they are evaluated left-to-right. In C++, the built-in comma operator also evaluates left-to-right (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), under "Built-in comma operator").

Comment: Ok but will it work the same if I write same code in C# ? Like this(in C#): `for(int l = 1 ; l <= c ; l++, Thread.Sleep(500*min(l, 8)))` ?? -- is it same as my C++ Version? (first version)

Comment: @user200312 The second form certainly works the same in both languages. I *believe* the first form does as well, because I think both languages define a left-to-right evaluation for the comma operator (not 100% sure, but I would be really surprised if this were false).

Comment: "I believe the first form does as well, because I think both languages define a left-to-right evaluation for the comma operator (not 100% sure, but I would be really surprised if this were false). " -- This is what I am actually interested in

Comment: @user200312 If that is really your intent with the question, then you should have asked that instead! And come to think of it, I'm not sure anymore whether C# has the comma operator. If it does, it should work the same. If not, the compiler will let you know.

Comment: "If that is really your intent with the question, then you should have asked that instead!" didn't think this would result in such loop complications

Comment: @user200312 I don't think it's a huge deal in this case, but this is the problem with making assumption when asking questions. The key to asking good questions is separating the essential parts from the scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion about C# 'for' loops here - C# *does* allow the same type of 'for' loop as the original (C++?) code (i.e., multiple statements in the third section):

```
for (int l = 1; l <= c; l++, System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500 * Math.Min(l, 8)))
{
    //....
}
```

If you want to have yet *another* way of writing this - even though the 'for' loop above works:

```
int l = 1;
while (l <= c)
{
    //....
    l += 1;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500 * Math.Min(l, 8));
}
```